# how to detect object of interest in an image using classical CV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to detect a limit switch from an image using either monocular camera or stereo setup. I have one camera image of the limit switch attached.

I want to detect if the switch is present in the image and if it is, I want to know its location (for now, in pixels).

I have tried using template matching algorithms from opencv, but when I orient the switch a little bit, I get very poor results.

I am very new to this domain and would like to know how I can achieve this task. What are the methods which give reliable results and easy to implement? What are scale and rotation invariant techniques to acheive this? I want to detect the limit switch even if it is close or far or rotated.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/home/Documents/cpp/CV/test/POC_test1.bmp")
template = cv2.imread("/home/Documents/cpp/CV/test/template.jpg")

print(img.shape)
print(template.shape)

(h, w, _) = template.shape

methods = [cv2.TM_CCOEFF, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, cv2.TM_CCORR,
            cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]

for method in methods:
    img2 = img.copy()

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img2, template, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        location = min_loc
    else:
        location = max_loc

    bottom_right = (location[0] + w, location[1] + h)    
    cv2.rectangle(img2, location, bottom_right, 255, 5)
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (int(3840/3), int(2748/3)))
    cv2.imshow('Match', img2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: 1]

[image: Object matching with a crop from original image]
[image: Feature matching when the sensor is rotated]

Comment: Do some research on Google first!

Comment: Define "limit switch"!  Limit of what?

Comment: the object in the image is the limit switch. It is used to detect position of anything in its vicinity. I want to use it in some automation setup. For that I need to find the limit switch and take the robot closer to it. I have used template matching and SIFT feature matching. But I get bad results with both on rotation and occlusions

Comment: Can you post your images. Template matching is not intended to work on scale or rotation changes. Feature matching should work fine. There are plenty of example. Search Google.

Comment: you dumped your picture in the middle of the code block. it's not noticeable as a picture. I'll fix that for you...

Comment: and you need to show us how that picture changes when anything moves. we can't tell. -- *why* do you even want to do this visually? that task demands decent physical sensors, not a camera.

Comment: You might use something like https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics but You'll need to finetune it as your use cases is not related to common objects.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - I have added the resulting images I get by using ORB feature matching. I am using the camera because this is the only specific task in my project that needs accurate detection and pose estimation. For rest of it, the camera will only be used for obstacle avoidance

Comment: @rhn89 - will I need to create a new dataset for the task of detecting this object as it is very uncommon?

Comment: your code shows usage of SIFT. now you say you use ORB. did you try both? generally I would recommend SIFT over ORB.

Comment: also: as said already, you can forget about opencv's template matching for this. don't give it another thought.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a dataset with samples for your images and labels and then fine-tune yolo or other models with your data.

Comment: you know, you could just slap an easy to recognize marker on there... colored circles are easy to recognize.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can you link an example image?